# Scroll attached to horizzontal viewport instead of a table

Tags: javascript, css, sass, scrollbar

I am exploring an effective method to accomplish the following task:

My table features horizontal overflow scrolling. I aim to ensure that the scrollbar stays at the bottom of the viewport when a user chooses to view a number of rows that extend beyond the vertical viewport.

Any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: Show your code so that it can be seen where to make modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your horizontal scroll option in the table by adding some css

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

For the vertical, you can set the height manually of the parent element(eg. a div) and then set the overflow to scroll too.

```
height:200px;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

You can find more information about overflow at this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear earlier. 
The issue I'm encountering is that when the table's height surpasses the viewport size, the x-scrollbar gets pushed to the bottom of the table div. 
This makes it invisible to the user unless they scroll all the way down to the end of the table.

Comment: @Andrea Oh sorry! Could you post some example code please.